# Check List elements in C# and Python

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, windows-forms-designer

I have worked on Python and I am new in C#. I am trying to get familier with syntaxes and concepts. I have a problem with list.

For example, I will take a word from user. I will add it to a list and I will check if it is entered before because user can't give the same word second time. If it is not entered before add it to the list. If is is already in the list pass it.

In python:

```
check_list = list()
if word not in check_list:
    check_list.append(word)
else:
    pass
```

How can I do that in C# ???

Comment: If the order isn't important you might want to use a `HashSet<string>` as it will not allow you to insert duplicates and it's `Contains` runs in constant time.

Comment: Is that **HashSet** same with the **set** in Python ??

Comment: I'm not going to say it's exactly the same, but they should be roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> list;
if(!list.Contains(word)){
    list.Add(word)
}
```

I was trying to follow your example as closely as possible so I didn't add confusion, however if you new-up the list every time `!list.Contains(word)` will always be true.

Comment: If you want explicitly list of words, isn't it better to use `List<string>` than anonymous type?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn `var` doesn't mean an anonymous type it just means the type is inferred from the assignment.